# See through the second layer according the position of the third one - Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, layer

I am new here and sorry if my question is stupid and sorry for my English. 
  My problem is that I have three layers like on the image below.

[image]
  The background of "Layer 1" is blue and the color of "Layer 2" is green. Layer 3 has that image with transparent background. I want to remove the second layer according to the image margins. Wherever I move the image I need to remove the second layer. The wanted result is shown on the second image.

[image]

Comment: Hi, tonitox, welcome to StackOverflow! Don't worry if your English is bad, as someone will usually come along and edit your post to clarify it. You are going to have to describe what you mean a little more, though. What do you mean by 'remove according to the image margins'?

Comment: As it is shown on the second image. I mean that the second layer should be removed where is the image. I mean in the size of the image.  With other words the idea is to show the first layer exactly under the image.I hope you can understand me what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to name your objects so that you can program against them.  Because spaces make for bad variable names, let's call your objects as follows:

- Layer 1 = `blue`
- Layer 2 = `green`
- Layer 3 = `person`

**Solution**

You need a mask, but unlike a normal mask, you want the inverse of the masking shape (ie., inside is *hidden* as opposed to inside is *shown*).  You can achieve this with [BlendMode.ERASE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BlendMode.html#ERASE).  Then, it's simply a matter of matching position & dimensions of `person`; whenever you move `person`, update the location of the mask as well.

```
function make(color:uint, width:Number, height:Number, x:Number = 0, y:Number = 0, existingShape:Sprite = null):Sprite {
    // Helper function to make squares.  Will create a new one, or draw on one provided.
    var s:Sprite;
    if (existingShape != null) {
        s = existingShape;
    } else {
        s = new Sprite();
    }
    s.graphics.beginFill(color, 1);
    s.graphics.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    s.graphics.endFill();
    return s;
}

// Layer 1
var blue:Sprite = make(0x3f48cc, 250, 400);
addChild(blue);

// Layer 2
var green:Sprite = make(0x00cc99, 250, 400);
addChild(green);
green.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;

// Layer 3
var person:Sprite = make(0xea0502, 20, 100, 20); // arms
make(0xea0502, 60, 20, 0, 20, person); // head and legs
addChild(person);
person.x = 95;
person.y = 150;

// This is the mask.  It must be a child of the object it is masking.
var boundary:Sprite = make(0xff00e4, person.width, person.height);
green.addChild(boundary);
boundary.x = person.x;
boundary.y = person.y;
boundary.blendMode = BlendMode.ERASE;
```

**Result**

[image]